# iteration getting stuck in loop(infinite loop) while tracking image

Tags: python, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray, opencv

Actually I was trying to build a Face recognition attendance system using Machine learning as I did everything when I click on the TrackImages button which calls the TrackImages() function, the face is properly tracked and recognized but the problem is that when the program enters in the loop, the loop executes till **attendence.loc[len(attendence)] = [Id,aa,date,timeStamp]** this line and then it again starts iterating it from the start of the While loop instead of marking the attendance in a newly created csv file as stated in the code. The program continues to track the face instead of finishing recognizing and marking attendance.
Plzzz help.....

```
def TrackImages():
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    recognizer.read(r"TrainingImageLabel\Trainner.yml")
    harcascadePath = "I:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath);
    df = pd.read_csv(r"StudentDetails\studentDetails.csv")
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    col_names = ['Id','Name','Date','Time']
    attendence = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
    while True:
        ret, im = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            if (conf <60):
                ts = time.time()
                date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                aa = df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
                tt = str(Id)+"-"+aa
                attendence.loc[len(attendence)] = [Id,aa,date,timeStamp]       
            else:
                Id = 'Unknown'
                tt = str(Id)
            if(conf>75):
                noOfFile = len(os.listdir("ImagesUnknown"))+1
                cv2.imwrite("ImagesUnknown\Image"+str(noOfFile)+".jpg", im[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            cv2.putText(im,str(tt), (x,y+h), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)
        attendence= attendence.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Id'], keep='first')
        cv2.imshow('im',im)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
            break
    ts = time.time()
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    Hour,Minute,Second = timeStamp.split(":")
    fileName = "Attendence\Attendence_" +date+"_"+ Hour+"-"+Minute+"-"+Second+".csv"
    attendence.to_csv(fileName,index=False)
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    res = attendence
    message1.configure(text = res)
```

Comment: Aree you intending to perform `attendence.to_csv(fileName,index=False)` on every loop of your `while True`? I don't see anywhere else in your code that youa re attempting to write to a file.

Comment: @currand60 yes! when the first if condition in the loop is true then It should mark the attendance by performing `attendence.to_csv(fileName,index=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your indentation. Currently it reads something like this:

```py
While True:
    for some_stuff in stuff:
        if (conf < 60):
            add a timestamp record to attendence.loc
        else:
            set some Id

        if (conf > 75):
            write an image file

    # This runs on every while loop
    cv2.imshow('im',im)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
            break

# This runs once while is no longer True (after pressing `q`)
ts = time.time()
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
Hour,Minute,Second = timeStamp.split(":")
fileName = "Attendence\Attendence_" +date+"_"+ Hour+"-"+Minute+"-"+Second+".csv"
attendence.to_csv(fileName,index=False)
```

So if you want those final lines to run every time, they need to be indented one step to be inside the `while` loop. However, this would not put a condition on writing the file and it would be done no matter what. You could create a function to timestamp and write the file:

```py
def write_file(attendance):
    ts = time.time()
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    Hour,Minute,Second = timeStamp.split(":")
    fileName = "Attendence\Attendence_" +date+"_"+ Hour+"-"+Minute+"-"+Second+".csv"
    attendence.to_csv(fileName,index=False)

While True:
    for some_stuff in stuff:
        if (conf < 60):
            add a timestamp record to attendence.loc
            write_file(attendence)
        else:
            set some Id

        if (conf > 75):
            write an image file

    # This runs on every while loop
    cv2.imshow('im',im)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
            break
```

Comment: Thank You so much! Issue Solved.